# Table initialization fails with a variable

Tags: c

I need to make a console program that prints the following output :

```
aaaaaaaaa
abbbbbbba
abcccccba
abcdddcba
abcdedcba
abcdddcba
abcccccba
abbbbbbba
aaaaaaaaa
```

So I made the following code, wich seems to work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int c, i = 0, p;

   scanf("%d", &c);

   int len = c*2-1;

   printf("%d\n", len);

   char ligne[9];

   while (i < len-1){
      p = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
         ligne[len-1-j] = p+97;
         ligne[j] = p+97;
         if (j < c && p < i)
            p++;
      }
     printf("%s\n", ligne);
      i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Which seems to work, but when I replace :

```
char ligne[9];
```

By :

```
char ligne[len];
```

I obtain the following output :

```
Your program output contains an invalid UTF8 character.
```

It seems that the table somehow "expanded" : there are much more than 9 fields in it.

I know that initializing tables with variables aren't allowed in some versions of C, but it ain't a problem for me. so, does anyone know where the prolem come from ?

Comment: BTW is your program giving correct outputs - as I am not getting

Comment: The program produces the top half of the table correctly; it does not reproduce the bottom half correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate 1 `char` extra space and explicitely add a NULL terminator to the array `ligne`.

```
char ligne[len + 1];

ligne[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: Well I tested it before posting and it is working. Must be some other problem at your end.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're trying to store 9 characters plus a terminal null into the space for 9 characters; this doesn't work.

Remove the `- 1` from your calculation of `len` and ensure that the string is null terminated.

It was only by accident it worked with the fixed length array.

You could also fix the problem by revising the `printf()` statement to:

```
printf("%.9s\n", ligne);
```

or:

```
printf("%.*s\n", len, ligne);
```

This doesn't require a null-terminated string any more.

The code in the question prints the top half of the output, but gets stuck printing the same line over and over again on the bottom half of the output.  This code fixes that, using the `min()` inline function to determine the maximum increment to be shown.  It also validates the return value from `scanf()` to ensure that the value in `c` is reasonable (1..26) — failing silently if it is not OK.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline int min(int i, int j) { return (i < j) ? i : j; }

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    if (scanf("%d", &c) == 1 && c >= 1 && c <= 26)
    {
        int len = c*2-1;

        printf("%d\n", len);

        char ligne[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            int p = 0;
            int maxinc = min(len-1-i, i);
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                ligne[len-1-j] = p + 'a';
                ligne[j] = p + 'a';
                if (p < maxinc)
                    p++;
            }
            printf("%.*s\n", len, ligne);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to add space for the null before posting, but It was useless.

Comment: It's no good just saying it's useless. You probably "fixed" it wrong. Post the code that you think is correct, but which still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I replaced "char ligne[len];" by "char ligne[len+1];", and it didn't work. But the printf technique was good.

Comment: Exactly what I meant, that's not going to do it. Extending the length of your array doesn't add a terminating null. Nobody can see that you've omitted to do this unless you post the code that you think is "fixed".

Comment: Yes, or initialize the entire array to zero when you define it, i.e. `char myarray[9] = {0};`, if you're sure you're never going to want a string shorter than the last one you used.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ligne[len+1];
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(ligne);++i)
    ligne[i]=0;
```